# Microsoft Access 2013 Enter Parameter Value

Tags: sql, forms, ms-access, search

Before this is written off as a duplicate, I have looked extensively for a situation similar to that of mine, which I have found, and have tried all the suggestions, but none have worked.

I am creating a database that edits, sorts, inputs and produces data for a hypothetical car rental company. The specific area of concern for me is the feature which searches for a specific type of car when parameters are inputted.

I am creating a query, using the query design view. The table I have used is called "Car Table". The fields I have used ALL come from that table. These fields include checkboxes, text entries and combo boxes.

For some further context, so far I have created a form (well, an amalgamation of several forms) which users have to enter a username/password to enter. Then they are taken to a home screen and can switch to several tabs; one which prints reports, one to enter or edit data, and one to find a specific car based on parameters.

In the car search page, I have created several text boxes and named them. To make this question a bit smaller, only one of these text boxes will be concerned. This text box is called "txtVIN" (VIN standing for Vehicle Identification Number).

Now, in the query design view, under the field car_VIN, I have written the critera "=[Forms]![Find a Car Form]![txtVIN]"

To my knowledge, the above code should search for whatever is currently written in the 'txtVIN' textbox of the 'Find a Car Form' and return all results that are identical (I will determine later how to search for similar and not exact results).

However, all that happens when I press 'run' is that a text box comes up titled 'enter parameter value'. Underneath the title it says "Forms!Find a Car Form!txtVIN" and has a blank textbox. If i enter the exact value into this textbox and press 'OK' it will show every field that has that exact value, but the textbox on the Find A Car form has no effect on this result.

For reference, here is the SQL code (keep in mind I used design view to create this code):

```
SELECT [Car Table].Car_VIN, [Car Table].Car_Class, [Car Table].Car_BodyType, [Car Table].Car_Colour, [Car Table].Car_Make, [Car Table].Car_Model, [Car Table].Car_EngineType, [Car Table].Car_TransmissionType, [Car Table].Car_GPSAvailability, [Car Table].Car_BootSpace, [Car Table].Car_FuelConsumptRate, [Car Table].Car_SeatNumber, [Car Table].Car_GreenStarRating, [Car Table].Car_ANCAPSafetyRating
FROM [Car Table]
WHERE ((([Car Table].Car_VIN)=[Forms]![Find a Car Form]![txtVIN]));
```

I am almost certain there are no spelling mistakes.

Just to clarify, my desired result is that I can type something into the txtVIN textbox, run the query, and obtain all the results that are similar or exact (I can figure out how to find similar results rather than exact results by myself hopefully).

I am VERY new to Access, in fact I used it for the first time 3 days ago, meaning that if possible I would like you to dumb your answers down a bit for me to understand, thanks!

Edit: I recently tried setting the query to check two parameters (if the VIN is the same as entered and if the 'Class' is the same as entered) and it yielded, low and behold, two instances of the 'enter parameter value' pop-up boxes. Just thought that this might be somehow useful.

Edit: For those saying the question is unclear; my issue is that when i try to run my query, instead of the query drawing parameters from a text box in a form, it brings up a window that says "enter parameter value". I do not want this window to come up, I want the parameters to be drawn from the text box in the form.

Comment: I can see no obvious mistake here. If your form is called "Find a Car Form", and if it is open when you run the query, it should work. --- The parameter prompt means that Access can't evaluate "[Forms]![Find a Car Form]![txtVIN]" (i.e. it doesn't find the form or the textbox) when running the query.

Comment: @Andre451 I'm not sure if this will make a difference, but I've just thought of something. My forms are inside a navigation form; perhaps this has something to do with it? maybe I need different notation in order to specify the location of the form that is in the navigation form. I'm pretty sure that i'm wrong about this, but it's worth a guess.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the form is a subform, you need to specify the "full path" through the forms to the textbox. E.g.

```
[Forms]![Navigation Form]![Subform Control Name].Form![txtVIN]
```

`[Subform Control Name]` is probably `[Find a Car Form]`, but it is not necessarily identical to the subform name.

Comment: I tried the above, but it didn't end up working, I still get the pop up box, but now it says "Forms!Navigation Form!Find A Car Form.Form!txtVIN" (yes, my navigation form is definitely called "Navigation Form"). Maybe i'm wrong about the control name? I'm unsure as to what a control name is. Just to clarify, when i say that my forms are inside a navigation form, I mean that I have a navigation form with tabs that have other forms. I plan to have a little datasheet view in the page, but I'll figure out how to do that after I get the main search function working.

Comment: Re *"I'm unsure as to what a control name is"*: Open the navigation form in Design View.  Click the subform control to select it.  Then open its property sheet and confirm it says *"Selection type: Subform/Subreport"* just below the *"Property Sheet"* heading.  If it says *"Selection type: Form"*, that is not the subform **control** ... keep searching until you've selected the control.  Then note its name and replace `[Subform Control Name]` with that name.

Comment: Thanks @HansUp. BlueRhapsody: The important thing is to click the subform only **once**. If you click it twice, you have moved the design focus into the subform itself.